# finding checked items in a list with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I am pretty new to Jquery and I am desining an asp.net repeater that list out Program Names and has a nested repeater inside for the programs associated the names. Inside this nested repeater are input type checkboxes. It would be great to alert (for testing purposes which one has been selected. My code below is a little off, can someone help me get where i am going. Thanks

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="r_programs" runat="server">

            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="ProgramsWrapper">
                <div>
                <ul>                    
<li id='<%# ((Program)Container.DataItem).ProgramId  %>'><%# ((Program)Container.DataItem).Name  %>  </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <Core:CoreRepeater ID="subAgencies" runat="server" DataSource=" <%# ((CCLContact.Business.Program)Container.DataItem).Children %>">
                    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="pro">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="programs" />  <%# ((CCLContact.Business.Program)Container.DataItem).Name %>    </li>

                        </ul>
                </div>
                </ItemTemplate>             
            </Core:CoreRepeater>
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

AND the JQuery

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#pro').prop('checked', true))
    alert("checked");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error?  Try changing this

```
var n = $("#programs:checked").length;
```

to

```
var n = $(".programs:checked").length;
```

the change was # to . as the input have a class of programs not id.  Id uses # and classes .